# Music player with all functionalities , play, pause, stop, next , previous using service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-mediaplayer

i am working on a music player app. I have created playlist, and i want to use service component for player functions like play, pause, previous, next, stop, shuffle etc..

For this i have found this answer at [Sending Commands to service from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909115/sending-commands-from-activity-to-service-in-android) and according to it , there are two different ways for doing this(giving commands to service for handling all music player functions), one is using local service and another is by using broadcast receiver.

So my question is that, which of the following method should I choose or best in terms of efficiency and simplicity. And in future versions I want to add video playing feature, so  answer accordingly.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nirmal, i have seen this tutorial. It is helpful for basic functionalities of music player, but in this tutorial service component is not used and my question is related to communication between activity and service.

Comment: i think you didn't understand my question, i am not asking - how to create media player, i am asking how can an activity component communicate or commands service component.

Comment: Local service is probably simpler to implement, but every developer will have his/her own opinion (based on experience) on this. Pick one and use it. There isn't enough difference to worry about it.

Comment: Hi david, thanks. I am trying massage handler. let's see it works for me or not..

Comment: I used message handler and working smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/tree/master/src/com/android/music

Every Best application of Music Player using **Broadcast Receiver** for all the operations like play-pause-stop-next-previous.

Create Constants and respective **ACTION** and broadcast them. Using Service handle them.

Handling this Events via Broadcast Receiver will be helpful to you in handling Events from **Notification and Widgets** via **single set of  SERVICES which are handling events of play-pause-stop-next-previous.**