# use startService() repeatedly over time to send commands to started service

Tags: android, android-service

I'm developing an app that communicates with an embedded device via BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy). The app allows the user to send commands via an activity. Meanwhile the app needs to send location data in the background. The location data must be sent constantly, even if the activity is closed and opened multiple times over the day.

I cannot separate the continues location updates from the command requests. Because all BLE transmissions must be synchronized by one queue to prevent simultaneous transmissions which would cause package loss.

After reading the official guide (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Basics), my first idea was to use a foreground service because the service must not be terminated when the activity is closed. That works fine for sending the location data. However, for sending the commands I have to communicate with the service after it has been started. I read that it's not recommended to use both `startService()` and `bindService()` but instead to decide for one way. As far as I understood a bound service can be destroyed when the referencing context (the activity in my case) is destroyed. So I guess binding to the service is not an option for me.

Another approach to talk to a started service is to send commands using broadcasts and receiving them in the service ([sending commands from Activity to Service in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909115/sending-commands-from-activity-to-service-in-android)).

But I think there must be a better solution that I miss. What came to my mind is simply **calling `startService()` every time I want to send a Bluetooth command. I guess that would work. But is it good practice?** Effectively, I would call `startService()` dozens of times during a typical use case before calling `stopService()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow... I read through the whole guide but overlooked this sentence in the method documentation:

startService()

> Every call to this method will result in a corresponding call to the target service's onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method, with the intent given here. **This provides a convenient way to submit jobs to a service without having to bind and call on to its interface.**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startService(android.content.Intent)

Hope it helps in case that someone stumbles across it..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to bind the service to anything. It's enough to start it and then make sure you call startForeground on it. That will keep your process running without being killed by the system. You don't have to place your BLE code in the service class but can have it wherever you want.